# Валидация булевских полей при десерилизации xml

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток уважаемые пользователи.
Я в с# полный профан, хотел бы у более опытных попросить помощи.

Есть xml-ка, в ней поле:

```
<data.xml>
  <value> true </value>
</data.xml>
```

И код:

```
Config = json;
getValue = Config.ContainsKey("value") && Config["value"].GetBool();
```

Ищем в xml-ке ключ "value" и присваиваем переменной getValue ее значение.
Все работает нормально, но если в поле "value" строка, а не логический элемент получаем ошибку:

> Only bool values can be converted to bool

Как реализовать проверку, если значение из поля "value" логический элемент, то присваиваем его переменной getValue, иначе пропускаем действие.

Comment: А что за классы вы используете? Что такое `json`, `GetBool()`? Ну и можно использовать `bool.TryParse()`

Comment: Re: Что такое json?

Comment: using RT.Util.Json;

Comment: Что говорит техподдержка библиотеки, что вы используете, или ее документация?

Comment: tym32167, спасибо за наводку. Доки помогли. https://docs.timwi.de/T:RT.Util.Json.JsonRaw